# Is it possible to write a program without variables in C#?

Tags: c#, variables

So me and my friend have received a programming task of implementing this function:

[image: function image]

So you have to input x and output y.
As is, it's really easy, but here's the thing: can we do that without variables, by using just one instance of Console.ReadLine() (and parsing it to double) and then passing the result to multiple "if" checks? Using new classes and methods is also cheating: we have to do everything in main().

Here's the example of this program with one variable:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            double x;
            x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (x < -2.0) { Console.Write(2.0); }
            if ((x < -1.0)&&(x>=-2.0)) { Console.Write(1.0); }
            if ((x < 0.0)&&(x>=-1)) { Console.Write(0.0); }
            if ((x>=0.0)&&(x<1.0)) { Console.Write(x); }
            if (x >= 1.0) { Console.Write(1.0); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any function mapping R -> R with a finite number of input ranges and output values should be implementable with a single switch statement. (edit: actually, you need switch on expressions - which is coming to C# vnext I believe).

Comment: @clcto Well, it's pretty much just silly fun, it's not the actual assignment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, first things first, your current program is defining the variable `args`.  You need to not do that, since you can't declare variables.  Change the declaration of `Main` to:

```
static void Main()
{
     //...
}
```

You can just use some form of external state to store whatever value you would normally store in a variable, for example, by always reading/writing the value to a file:

```
File.WriteAllText("line.txt", Console.ReadLine());

if (double.Parse(File.ReadAllText("line.txt")) < -2.0)
    Console.Write(2.0);
if ((double.Parse(File.ReadAllText("line.txt")) < -1.0)
    && (double.Parse(File.ReadAllText("line.txt")) >= -2.0))
    Console.Write(1.0);
if ((double.Parse(File.ReadAllText("line.txt")) < 0.0)
    && (double.Parse(File.ReadAllText("line.txt")) >= -1))
    Console.Write(0.0);
if ((double.Parse(File.ReadAllText("line.txt")) >= 0.0)
    && (double.Parse(File.ReadAllText("line.txt")) < 1.0))
    Console.Write(double.Parse(File.ReadAllText("line.txt")));
if (double.Parse(File.ReadAllText("line.txt")) >= 1.0)
    Console.Write(1.0);
File.Delete("line.txt");
```

You could do the same thing with a registry value, getting/posting values to a web service, etc.  These are all ungodly inefficient, of course, but it's a toy example.

Now of course, in addition to being super inefficient, this also looks a mess.  We can actually make this look notably better by using methods.  Our methods can't have any parameters, since parameters are variables, but a parameterless method that returns the parsed line does wonders for the readability here:

```
public static void Main()
{
    File.WriteAllText("line.txt", Console.ReadLine());

    if (GetValue() < -2.0)
        Console.Write(2.0);
    if (GetValue() < -1.0 && GetValue() >= -2.0)
        Console.Write(1.0);
    if (GetValue() < 0.0 && GetValue() >= -1)
        Console.Write(0.0);
    if (GetValue() >= 0.0 && GetValue() < 1.0)
        Console.Write(GetValue());
    if (GetValue() >= 1.0)
        Console.Write(1.0);
    File.Delete("line.txt");
}
public static double GetValue()
{
    return double.Parse(File.ReadAllText("line.txt"));
}
```

Comment: Ok, you win the prize for thinking outside the box!

Comment: This should be, without doubt, the accepted answer. +1 for the idea

Comment: Well, my friend, it seems you are the winner!

Comment: We can just leave it sub-optimal - as I stated, we can't use new methods.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you define "variable" ☺

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("line", Console.ReadLine());
switch((int)Math.Floor(Double.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("line"))))
{
    case -2:
        Console.Write("1.0");
        break;
    case -1:
        Console.Write("0.0");
        break;
    case 0:
        Console.Write(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("line"));
        break;
    default:
        if(Double.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("line")) > 0)
        {
            Console.Write("1.0");
        }else{
            Console.Write("2.0");
        }
        break;
}
```

No locals, parameters, fields, or properties used.

Comment: Properties are not variables in C#.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but they are usually backed with fields, so using them could count as using a field.

Answer (score 0):

This won't get you to 0 variables but it does truly only have 1.

**EDIT**

To the point @Servy raised in the comment, the initial answer below does still use a variable (args), but this was not counted in the OP so I felt that it was a legitimate answer.

If you'd like a solution with 0 variables that doesn't rely on storage that could fail (e.g. no file system access, no registry access, etc.) this will do it.

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Title = Console.ReadLine();
        if (double.Parse(Console.Title) < -2.0) { Console.Write(2.0); }
        if ((double.Parse(Console.Title) < -1.0) && (double.Parse(Console.Title) >= -2.0)) { Console.Write(1.0); }
        if ((double.Parse(Console.Title) < 0.0) && (double.Parse(Console.Title) >= -1)) { Console.Write(0.0); }
        if ((double.Parse(Console.Title) >= 0.0) && (double.Parse(Console.Title) < 1.0)) { Console.Write(double.Parse(Console.Title)); }
        if (double.Parse(Console.Title) >= 1.0) { Console.Write(1.0); }
    }
}
```

**Original Answer Below**

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            Main(new string[] { Console.ReadLine() });
        }
        else
        {
            if (double.Parse(args[0]) < -2.0) { Console.Write(2.0); }
            if ((double.Parse(args[0]) < -1.0) && (double.Parse(args[0]) >= -2.0)) { Console.Write(1.0); }
            if ((double.Parse(args[0]) < 0.0) && (double.Parse(args[0]) >= -1)) { Console.Write(0.0); }
            if ((double.Parse(args[0]) >= 0.0) && (double.Parse(args[0]) < 1.0)) { Console.Write(double.Parse(args[0])); }
            if (double.Parse(args[0]) >= 1.0) { Console.Write(1.0); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the requirement is zero, not one.

Comment: Except that the OP (mistakenly) did not consider that arguments passed to Main as counting against them.  This solution did eliminate the `x` and doesn't rely on other storage (e.g. files, env variables, etc.) and therefore represents a unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with regex, but it is rather ugly. Values -1 and -2 have to be handled separately and there are huge problems with E in number representation. I wrapped the solution into test loop.

```
//test loop
for (double x = -4; x < 4; x += 0.2d)
{
    Console.Write(x.ToString().PadRight(20, ' ') + " => ");
    string readLine = x.ToString();

    //original main
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(Math.Max(-2, Math.Min(1, double.Parse(
        Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(
            Math.Max(-3, double.Parse(readLine)).ToString()//format normalization
            , "-1$", "0") // -1 -> 0
            , "-2$", "-1") // -2 -> -1
            , @"^-.*E-.*", @"0") // -5E-5 -> 0
            , @"^(-\d+)\D.*", @"$1")))))); // -2.22 -> -2
    //end of main
}
```

the result is

```
-4                   => 2
-3,8                 => 2
-3,6                 => 2
-3,4                 => 2
-3,2                 => 2
-3                   => 2
-2,8                 => 2
-2,6                 => 2
-2,4                 => 2
-2,2                 => 2
-2                   => 1
-1,8                 => 1
-1,6                 => 1
-1,4                 => 1
-1,2                 => 1
-0,999999999999999   => 0
-0,799999999999999   => 0
-0,599999999999999   => 0
-0,399999999999999   => 0
-0,199999999999999   => 0
1,27675647831893E-15 => 1,27675647831893E-15
0,200000000000001    => 0,200000000000001
0,400000000000001    => 0,400000000000001
0,600000000000001    => 0,600000000000001
0,800000000000001    => 0,800000000000001
1                    => 1
1,2                  => 1
1,4                  => 1
1,6                  => 1
1,8                  => 1
2                    => 1
2,2                  => 1
2,4                  => 1
2,6                  => 1
2,8                  => 1
3                    => 1
3,2                  => 1
3,4                  => 1
3,6                  => 1
3,8                  => 1
```

Answer (score -2):

This works, no variables declared:

```
static void Main()
{
    (new Action<double>(x =>
    {
        if (x < -2.0) { Console.Write(2.0); }
        if ((x < -1.0) && (x >= -2.0)) { Console.Write(1.0); }
        if ((x < 0.0) && (x >= -1)) { Console.Write(0.0); }
        if ((x >= 0.0) && (x < 1.0)) { Console.Write(x); }
        if (x >= 1.0) { Console.Write(1.0); }
    }))(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: This is declaring the variable `x`.  That you don't explicitly declare the type doesn't mean that you're not declaring the variable.

Comment: @Servy x is not a variable, its a parameter.

Comment: All parameters *are variables*.  Parameters are one type of variable.  Locals are another, instance fields are another, etc.  They're still all variables.

Comment: @Servy in general yes but in my opinion in the context of this question he's referring to a variable as an explicitly defined variable `double x;`

Comment: He didn't say, "local variable".  He said, "variable".  That's unambiguous in its meaning.  Your answer is *explicitly defining a variable*.  You're inferring the type of the variable, but you're still *explicitly defining that variable*.

Comment: @Servy then there's no solution to this problem without switch on expressions

Comment: Considering I've already posted a solution to the problem that uses no variables (8 minutes before you even posted your answer, in fact), that is clearly false.

Answer (score -4):

To answer the question. Yes. Simple replace every instance of `x` with `double.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`.

Comment: Although then you'd need to enter the exact same value multiple times on the console input, sadly.

Comment: Yes - of course. That's why we have variable. To save the results of calculations. If you want to use no variables you have to reproduce the calculation every time. What else do you want - magic?

Comment: That would require a lot of user input, I don't think that's what he is looking for.

Comment: @clcto yep, but if you've got a stupid pointless requirement, don't be surprised if your code ends up redundant and foolish.

Comment: well then, if you *can't* do it, the answer to his question is *NOT Yes*, as you said.

Comment: No, it's Yes. He didn't specify the user wouldn't have to enter the input multiple times.

Comment: @DrewJordan - oh ok ok... so he did... you're right

Comment: Although we could use reflection on Console to avoid calling ReadLine directly - is that allowed?

Comment: Dunno, you'd have to ask them. I was just trying to clarify that this doesn't answer the question as asked is all. I'd assume not as this sounds like a school assignment to me.

Comment: @JamesGaunt What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Yes, we can't input our double multiple times, that's the whole point)

Comment: Which bit? The reflection? You can call any method in C# using reflection. So you can call "Console.ReadLine" without writing "Console.ReadLine"... but it's just silly (as it was from the start of course).

Comment: So really you need switch on expressions which are coming - but then that is just syntactic sugar for your if/else statement with a variable.

Comment: @JamesGaunt But, as I understand, it would still require multiple inputs?

Comment: No because it only evaluates the switch input once, but the case statements can be expressions.  Hmmmm, ok so it's still really a variable because the switch statement creates a local variable.... ok... answer must be no. At the end of the day if you want to "remember" the input you need to "remember" it somewhere... whether you call that "memory" a variable or not comes down to syntactic sugar.

Comment: @JamesGaunt Well, as long as we don't have to explicitly create a variable and initialize it, this qualifies.